# MacOS Sierra - USB boot failure

Tags: macos, installation

I want to install the new Mac os `Sierra`.
I don't want a upgrade - I want a clean new installation. Therefore I created a bootable USB stick with the following command

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app
```

The operation completed successfully but when I'm trying to boot the Installer Stick I am getting a error after a few minutes. First I see the "Apple" and then at about 50 percent I'm getting a crossed circle, like a "Stop".

The SHA-hash of the software is OK. 
Any ideas?

Edit
MacBook Pro (Retina, 15", late 2013);2 GHz Intel Core i7; 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3; Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB
OS Version 10.11.6

Comment: Exact Mac model & current OS might help. I don't see anything wrong with your createinstallmedia command in itself, but some Macs are just more difficult to boot from USB than others, especially if they came with a Superdrive

Comment: @Tetsujin, sorry.. i added the informations above :)

Comment: OK, that should work no probs - I'd try a different USB stick first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two new sticks... it worked :/